# How to use sqlite in angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, sqlite

I have to used below code for using sqlite inside angulajs.but i got error like,
Module name "sqlite3" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
please help me

```
 var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('mydb.sqlite');
db.serialize(function() {
    console.log("A");
    db.run("CREATE TABLE if not exists lorem (info TEXT)");
    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
    }
    stmt.finalize();
    db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
        console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
    });
});
db.close();
```

Comment: web app or mobile app?

Comment: webapplication only.....

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use sqlite3 in angularjs web application directly, because angularjs is client-side frontend framework, and sqlite is a database and a part of the backend.

So you can only use sqlite in your application via backend services implemented on the server side (nodejs, java, ...). And if you need browser data storage mechanism, you can use IndexedDB.

See the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893817/how-to-integrate-sqlite-with-angularjs).

Comment: You can take working example from [here](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/node-sqlite-tutorial/). It's work for me, but I had to change version for sqlite3 to * (latest) in package.json, because it was the problem with my environment (node 4.4.3, npm 2.15.1).